# Make Date#parse assume a US format instead of an EU format

Tags: ruby, date

With 1.9.2p0, Date#parse assumes an UE format.  Check out format.rb, line: 1042 if you don't believe me.

Anyways, how can I make it assume a US format, so that:

```
> Date.parse("10/4/2010")
 => Mon, 04 Oct 2010
```

Instead of April 10th.

I've tried this:

```
class Date
  def _parse_eu(str,e)
    _parse_us(str,e)
  end
end
```

but no luck.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I just compared Ruby 1.8.7's format.rb to 1.9.2's and they both test for _parse_eu() before _parse_us().

Comment: Yea, more digging and it's neither of those methods that catch a format like "10/2/2010" -- Something has changed in _parse_ddd as well as something else I haven't quite figured out.

Comment: looks like it's flat out not supported:

Comment: http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/634

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[Date.strptime](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/date/Date#strptime-class_method) is what you want but unfortunately it doesn't look like the documentation  has the date formatting strings. I got the following to work based on Googling for the format strings:

```
1.9.2 > d = Date.strptime("10/4/2010", "%m/%d/%Y")
=> #<Date: 2010-10-04 (4910947/2,0,2299161)> 
1.9.2 > d.day
=> 4 
1.9.2 > d = Date.strptime("10/4/2010", "%d/%m/%Y")
=> #<Date: 2010-04-10 (4910593/2,0,2299161)> 
1.9.2 > d.day
=> 10
```

Comment: Date formatting directives are those used by `strftime`, which can be found here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime

Comment: Looks like the link you provided in your answer is no longer valid, here's another: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime

Comment: Updated link to latest documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Date.html#M000643) instead.