# Set date in text_field rails 3.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, datetime

I have just upgraded to rails 3.2.1.

I use the jQuery UI datepicker to set dates in rails text_fields. The field sets a date column in the database.

But, now it does not work.

I have this code in the view.

```
<%= p.text_field :due, :value => Time.now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"), :id => "dialog_project_date" %>
```

If I don't change the date all goes well. If I change the date Rails puts `nil` in the database. This also happens when I disable jQuery datepicker and enter the date (with the right format) manually.

It seems to me that there is something with the way rails handles the formatting of the date field.

I can't find a solution. Does anybody have an idea?

**Update**

I used the debugger in the create action. Here's the otuput

```
 (rdb:22) params
 {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"4IChBeyKzkc4dwzje1RMPy2GBTMs5m2zrBPBFbIIKJw=",         "project"=>{"name"=>"gunnaer", "description"=>"", "due"=>"03/17/2012", "customer_id"=>""},     "commit"=>"Save", "controller"=>"projects", "action"=>"create_index"}
 (rdb:22) @project
 #<Project id: nil, name: "gunnaer", description: "", due: nil, active: true, budget:   nil, hour_price: nil, firm_id: 1, customer_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
 (rdb:22) @project.due = "03/17/2012"
 "03/17/2012"
 (rdb:22) @project
 #<Project id: nil, name: "gunnaer", description: "", due: nil, active: true, budget:  nil, hour_price: nil, firm_id: 1, customer_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

The params is right, but the due param does not get set to the instans variable. The format is the same when I do not change the date. When I do not change it, it works.
Strange..

Comment: What Rails ver did you update from? Did it work for that ver?

Comment: updated from 3.1 and it did work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date format is wrong. Try using "yyyy/mm/dd"

This works:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > b = Blog.first
 => #<Blog id: 1, title: "Something", created_at: "2012-03-09 13:38:23", updated_at: "2012-03-09 13:38:32"> 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :003 > b.created_at
 => Fri, 09 Mar 2012 13:38:23 UTC +00:00 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :004 > b.created_at = "2012/03/17"
 => "2012/03/17" 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :005 > b.save
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :006 > Blog.first
 => #<Blog id: 1, title: "Something", created_at: "2012-03-17 00:00:00", updated_at: "2012-03-09 13:58:55">
```

This does not:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :007 > b.created_at = "03/17/2012"
 => "03/17/2012" 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :008 > b.save
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :009 > Blog.first
 => #<Blog id: 1, title: "Something", created_at: nil, updated_at: "2012-03-09 13:59:22">
```

EDIT

You have a few options for date format, which you should specify in your jquery ui code. See this link for examples - http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/date-formats.html

Comment: This is right. Thank you! I repied so late because I foud the solution my self.

Answer (score 0):

To debug, first see what values are being POSTed to your controller. Either check the log or use a debugging proxy such as fiddle.

Then use the Rails console to isolate where the problem is happening.

**UPDATED**

The problem is that latest ver of Ruby (not Rails) assumes European date formats. A work-around to still use [US format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756856/make-dateparse-assume-a-us-format-instead-of-an-eu-format)